# redirect to an external url with request parameters

Tags: java, jsp

I need to redirect user to an external url from my java application whenever a button is clicked.

url: https://example.org?x=12345&y=ab

the parameters to be passed in url has to be calculated dynamically. It will be different for different users.

Could any one provide pointers to it?

I am not sure if HttpClient or HttpUrlConnection will do a redirect from my application to the new url

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the following code line :

```
response.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
```